# What's the best way to raise a number to the power of a fractional exponent in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I am trying to raise a number to a fractional exponent in solidity. I have tried using the Bancor (https://github.com/bancorprotocol/contracts-solidity/blob/v0.3.1/solidity/contracts/BancorFormula.sol) power function but it keeps losing some digits or decimals but when I try their calculatePurchaseReturn function it works fine.

Here is what I tried with the Bancor power function:

if I do: `(uint256 result, uint8 precision) = power(4, 1, 2, 1);` I get 15 instead of 16.
I have another equation here: `(uint256 result, uint8 precision) = power((120000 * 1e18), 1, 333300, 1000000);` I get 49218474 instead of something like 49305016...

In this equation above 333300 is a decimal represented in PPM(parts per million)

Comment: Just use the `pow` function in [PRBMath](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/prb-math).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the `pow` function of [PRBMath](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/prb-math). Here's an example:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.22;

import { UD60x18, ud } from "@prb/math/src/UD60x18.sol";

contract Foo {
    function doPow() external pure returns (UD60x18 result) {
        UD60x18 x = ud(2e18);
        UD60x18 y = ud(1.5e18);
        result = x.pow(y); // will be 2.828427124746190097
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Didn't know about the PRBMath library. It would've saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Happy to help. Maybe it will save you time from now on!

Answer (score 1):

This library is amazing. Thanks!